# Using a graphing calculator to find values in interval that satisfy Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculator

> $f(x) = 2^x - \sin x, [0,π]$

I believe the question wants me to find the values x within the interval that have the same slope as the secant line?

The secant line would be:
$$ f'(c) = \frac{f(π) - f(0)}{π - 0}$$ which is
$$ f'(c) = \frac{2^π - 1}{π}$$

The derivative of f(x) is:
$$f'(x) = 2^x\ln2 - \cos x$$

In my calculator (TI-84 Plus) I am plotting the graph of f'(x) and then pressing calculate for the value of f'(c). Depending on my input I either get the wrong answer or I get a syntax error. What is the correct method of doing this on a graphing calculator?

Comment: You made a mistake $$ f'(c) = \frac{2^{\pi}}{\pi}$$ So you have to solve $$2^x \log 2-\cos x=\frac{2^{\pi }}{\pi }$$ I got $x\approx 1.86285$

Comment: @Raffaele What is the process that you took to find the answer on the calculator?

Comment: I used *Mathematica* to find so many digits. Otherwise you can use this site and zoom until you get the desired number of decimals of the intersection with the $x$-axis https://www.desmos.com/calculator/swu9bqbzm4

Comment: @Raffaele What would I have to do to get the answer on a graphing calculator? Do I graph out the derivative and calculate for the value f'(c) (I get 2.4 if I do this)? Or is it something else

Comment: Don't know TI-84, but you should plot $2^x\log 2-\cos x-\frac{2^{\pi}}{\pi}$ and look for the intersection with $x$-axis

Comment: @Raffaele You made a mistake,  $f'(c) = \frac{2^{\pi}-1}{\pi}$